# Oracle SQL: Order By numerical and alphabetical order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called "countries" and a column named "val" that is VARCHAR2(2 CHAR). I have some problems with the order of the values from this column.
I will not write all values(359) from "val" just a few for example:

```
'AD','EC','XX','1C','1D','MR','4R','1E','TO','SK'
```

And I want to order the values in numerical order and than in alphabetical order:

```
'1C','1D','1E','4R','AD','EC','MR','SK','TO','XX'.
```

I wrote something like this:

`SELECT val
FROM countries
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN val LIKE '[1-9]%'
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END ASC;`
and everything works fine except that the first two values '1C' and '1D' are shown at the end of the table and not at the beginning. It's very strange. I have Oracle 12c. 
I need help !!

Comment: `order by case when val >= '0' and val < ':' then 0 else 1 end, val`

Comment: Is `ORDER BY val` not giving you correct result? Because digits sort before alphabets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `LIKE`.  If you only care about the first value, you can just use string comparisons:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN SUBSTR(val, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
               THEN 0 ELSE 1
          END) ASC,
         val
```

Comment: It worked. Can you explain very short why this behavior works as expected? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @blackout1701 . . . This is implementing the logic that you want . . . comparing the first string.  Your version doesn't work because Oracle does not support character classes in `LIKE` patterns.